# Why I get Error 2042 as Result of VBA Match using Statement as shown in MS documentation

Tags: excel, vba, string, match

I have a Woorsheet (TMP) with 2 Columns (A+B). In Col A there are Numbers as String, in Col B there are numbers. Now I try to get the corresponding number to a given String.

I've tried a lot of things allready, nothing helped. As far as I understand the code of the match statement is the same as the one in the docunentation of MS. 
I even did the same with a foreach loop, which worked fine but is a little bit slow.

```
Public Function SuchenKonto(Konto As String) As Boolean
    Dim ind As Variant
    Dim Rückgabe As Boolean
    Dim Vergl As Variant
    Vergl = Konto
    Rückgabe = False

    ind = Application.Match(Konto, Worksheets("TMP").Columns(1), 0)


    If Not IsError(ind) Then
        Rückgabe = True
        Worksheets("TMP").Range("B" & ind).Copy
        Sheets("Monatsvergleich").Range("AD1").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, Transpose:=False
    End If
    SuchenKonto = Rückgabe

End Function
```

What can I do to get back the index of the line with the correct dates?

Comment: a function is used to get results, not copy and paste.

Comment: What do you mean with 'a function is used to get results...? I have no problems with the commands in the IF-Block. I get the error from the Match-function.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the first parameter of the Match-function has to be the value in a Cell. After adding the following line before the line with the Match-function

Sheets("TMP").Range("H1").Cells(1, 1).Value = Konto

and changing the line with the Match-function into

ind = Application.Match(Sheets("TMP").Range("H1").Cells(1, 1).Value, Workbooks(m_WBKum).Worksheets("TMP").Columns(1), 0)

it works without further errors.